# Trying to order a query by using a variable from a different query

Tags: c#, sql

So I tried doing this:

```
public List<User> GetLeaderBoard()
       {
           SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext myDB = new SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext();
           var userResults = (from u in myDB.Users
                              orderby (GetUserPoints(u.userID))
                              select u).Take(100);
           List<User> users = new List<User>();
           foreach (var usr in userResults)
           {
               if (usr.myPoints > 0)
                   users.Add(usr);
           }
           return users;
       }

       public int? GetUserPoints(int userId)
       {
           SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext myDB = new SuperGoalDataClassesDataContext();
           var codeResults = (from tc in myDB.TriviaCodes
                              where tc.userID == userId
                              select tc);
           return codeResults.Sum(cd => cd.pointsGained);
       }
```

But I'm getting an error saying "Method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] GetUserPoints(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL."

Any idea how I can get something like this to work?

Regards,

Arseney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for my English. You're code not working because in LINQ to SQL you can not use many contexts. You have many alternative options.
For example concatenating one to one with a subquery.

```
public List<User> GetLeaderBoard()
{
return (from u in myDB.Users
       select new {
                   User = u,
                   Sum = (from tc in myDB.TriviaCodes 
                          where tc.userID == u.userID 
                          select c).Sum(p => p == null ? 0 : p.pointsGained)
                  })
.OrderBy(g => g.Sum)
.Select(g => g.User)
.Take(100)
.Where(u => u.myPoints > 0)
.ToList();
}
```

Or Use concatenating and grouping

```
public List<User> GetLeaderBoard()
{
return (from u in myDB.Users
        join tc in myDB.TriviaCodes on u.userID equals tc.userID into gj
        from subtc in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        group new { u, subtc } by u into g
        select g)
.OrderBy(g => g.Sum(p1 => p1.subtc == null ? 0 : p1.subtc.pointsGained))
.Select(g => g.Key)
.Take(100)
.Where(u => u.myPoints > 0)
.ToList();
}
```

I used where condition instead of this loop

```
 List<User> users = new List<User>();
 foreach (var usr in userResults)
 {
    if (usr.myPoints > 0)
    users.Add(usr);
 }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and no explanation was required :)
Other than the fact I needed it to be OrderByDescending ;)
Thank you!!!